# Drop rows with conditions in PySpark Pandas API

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, conditional-statements, drop

I would like to know how to do that using PySpark Pandas API.

This is Pandas version:

```
indexNames = dfObj[ (dfObj['Age'] >= 30) & (dfObj['Age'] <= 40) ].index
dfObj.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

But I would like to do that using PySpark Pandas API.

Could you please help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dude. I found the solution:

```
array = indexNames.to_numpy()   
dfObj = dfObj.drop(index = array)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should follow this guide initially:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/pandas_pyspark.html#pandas

example will look like this:

```py
import pyspark.pandas as ps

psdf = ps.range(10)
pdf = psdf.to_pandas()
pdf.values
```

And you can work how you like from this...

Comment: Thanks dude. I found the solution:

`array = indexNames.to_numpy()


dfObj = dfObj.drop(index = array)`